# Teamcity- has not .gitmodules configuration in the root directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bitbucket, teamcity

Facing Issue On Teamcity --

> Failed to build patch for build #27 {build id=3317287, buildTypeId=ABC_AbcTestBuild_BuildAbcTest}, VCS root: "ABC_VCS_Root" {instance id=59887, parent internal id=12858, parent id=ABCProj_ABCTestBuild_AbcVcsRoot, description: "https://abc@stash.abc.git#refs/heads/ABC_Dev_CreateEditMerge"}, due to error: 'build patch' command failed.
>
> stderr: The 'https://abc@stash.abc.git' repository has a submodule in the 'f1e673f5b8670a1d978434cd0a9275491c34c253bf' commit at the 'abc' path, but has not .gitmodules configuration in the root directory